# lock/prevent close of menu reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, state

I have a side menu that opens when an icon is clicked and closes when the either the page is clicked or an item on the menu is clicked. I am trying to implement a lock so when the lock icon is clicked, the menu will not close even if you click on a menu item or on the page.

I was able to setup the icon changing from a locked one to an unlocked one but I am having trouble with the functionality of stopping the close. Any help/suggestions would be awesome. Below are the 2 components that (the parent and the menu with the lock button) here is the code sandbox for a full look: https://codesandbox.io/s/pw6q46jp20

```js
class SideBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      category: props.category,
      currentPage: {
        backgroundColor: '#383838',
        color: '#A9A9A9',
      },
      menuLocked: false,
      menuOpen: false,
      selectedIcon: null,
    };
  }
  handleIconClick = (category) => {
    this.setState({
      category,
      menuOpen: true,
      selectedIcon: category,
    });
  };
  handleMenuItemClick = (category) => {
    this.setState({
      menuOpen: false,
      selectedIcon: '',
      currentPage: category,
    });
  }
  handlePageClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      menuOpen: false,
    });
  }
  handleMenuLock = () => {
    this.setState({ menuLocked: !this.state.menuLocked });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TopBar {...this.props} />
        <Container>
          <SideNav>
            <ListWrapper>
              <IconList
                currentPage={this.state.currentPage}
                openMenu={this.handleIconClick}
                selectedIcon={this.state.selectedIcon}
                visible={this.state.menuOpen}
              />
            </ListWrapper>
          </SideNav>
          <PageContentWrapper>
            <Sidebar.Pushable>
              <PushMenu
                category={this.state.category}
                closeOnItemClick={this.handleMenuItemClick}
                handleMenuLock={this.handleMenuLock}
                menuLocked={this.state.menuLocked}
                params={this.props.params}
                visible={this.state.menuOpen}
              />
              <Sidebar.Pusher
                onClick={this.handlePageClick}>
                <Segment basic>
                  {this.props.children || <Home />}
                </Segment>
              </Sidebar.Pusher>
            </Sidebar.Pushable>
          </PageContentWrapper>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SideBar.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any,
  params: PropTypes.any,
  category: PropTypes.any,
};

export default SideBar;
```

```js
class PushMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const category = sideNavData.lookupCategory(this.props.category);
    const menuLockButton = !this.props.menuLocked
      ? <Icon
        link={true}
        name='unlock'
        size='big'
      />
      : <Icon
        link={true}
        name='lock'
        size='big'
      />;
    return (
      <Sidebar
        className='Push-menu'
        animation='push'
        width='thin'
        visible={this.props.visible}
      >
        <Header>{this.props.category}</Header>
        <Linebreak />
        {
          Object.keys(category).map((subCategory, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <SubcategoryHeader>{subCategory}</SubcategoryHeader>
                <List>
                  {
                    Object.keys(category[subCategory]).map((item, index) => (
                      <li key={index}>
                        <ListLink>
                          <Link
                            to={`/${this.props.category}/${subCategory}/${category[subCategory][item].name}`}
                            activeStyle={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}
                            onClick={() => {
                              this.props.closeOnItemClick(this.props.category);
                            }}
                          >
                            {category[subCategory][item].name}
                          </Link>
                        </ListLink>
                      </li>
                    ))
                  }
                </List>
                <LockButtonWrapper onClick={this.props.handleMenuLock}>
                  {menuLockButton}
                </LockButtonWrapper>
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </Sidebar>
    );
  }
}

PushMenu.propTypes = {
  category: PropTypes.any,
  closeOnItemClick: PropTypes.func,
  currentPage: PropTypes.func,
  handleMenuLock: PropTypes.func,
  menuLocked: PropTypes.bool,
  visible: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default PushMenu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `handlePageClick()` you should do a check to see if `this.state.menuLocked` is true. If so, don't change the value of `menuOpen` in state.

```
handlePageClick = () => {
  if (!this.state.menuLocked) {
    this.setState({
      menuOpen: false,
    });
  }
}
```

As a side note, in `handleMenuLock()` you are using the previous value of `menuLocked` to set the new value. Since `setState` is asynchronous, it's entirely possible that the value of `menuLocked` has changed by the time it actually saves and so you may not get the desired result. As such, you should pass it a function like this:

```
handleMenuLock = () => {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({ menuLocked: !prevState.menuLocked }))
}
```

This ensures that the value is actually toggled. Docs on using `setState` in this manner can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `handlePageClick` method to setState only when `this.state.menuLocked` is false.

```js
  handlePageClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.menuLocked) {
      this.setState({
        menuOpen: false,
      });
    }
  }
```